# Ассемблер. Перемножить 2 32-х разрядных числа в DEBUG (i8086)

Tags: ассемблер, отладка

Есть массив из 17 элементов. Элемент массива - 32-х разрядное 16-ричное знаковое число (12223278h). В задании нужно перемножить с 3 по 5 элементы массива.

Для начала пытаюсь перемножить хотя бы 2 раза. Перемножаю, проверяю на калькуляторе - не сходится.

Вот код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```
mov cx,11;счетчик для цикла на 17 проходов для инициализации массива
mov dx,1222
mov ax,3278
not dx
neg ax;делаю число знаковым
mov bx,500;массив находится с 500 адреса в памяти
mov [bx],ax
mov [bx+2],dx
add bx,4
dec cx
jnz 110
mov bx,508
mov di,800;результаты перемножения храню с 800 адреса
mov bp,0
xor ax,ax
xor dx,dx
mov [di+4],dx;дальше начинаю перемножать
mov [di+6],dx
mov ax,[bx]
mov si,[bx+4]
imul si
mov [di],ax
mov [di+2],dx
mov ax,[bx]
mov si,[bx+6]
imul si
add [di+2],ax
adc [di+4],dx
adc [di+6],bp
mov ax,[bx+2]
mov si,[bx+4]
imul si
add [di+2],ax
adc [di+4],dx
adc [di+6],bp
mov ax,[bx+2]
mov si,[bx+6]
imul si
add [di+4],ax
adc [di+6],dx
```

[image: Скрин]

P.S. ответ калькулятора: 148D3AA51D31840

Comment: Ничего не понятно. 1) *mov cx,11;счетчик для цикла на 17 проходов* - это как??? 2) *Элемент массива - 32-х разрядное 16-ричное знаковое число (12223278h). В задании нужно перемножить с 3 по 5 элементы массива*  - зачем вам вообще массив, если достаточно вычислить `12223278h*12223278h*12223278h`?

Comment: Задание такое. Сначала требовалось создать массив таких чисел. Потом дали задание перемножить именно как элементы массива. Конечно понятно, что у меня все числа одинаковые, но суть задания в том, что надо именно из массива взять множители.

Comment: если вы не понимаете (не знаете), что такое счетчик и цикл, то зачем  вообще встревать? (организован цикл таким образом: mov cx,11; . . . ; dec cx; jnz <adr>)

Comment: И вообще суть вопроса не в этом. Я попросил помочь найти ошибку в умножении

Comment: @klopp - Никогда не работали с `debug`?  Когда набираешь программу в дебаге, все числа (без суффикса h) по умолчанию 16-ричные, поэтому `mov cx,11` означает 17 повторов цикла.  Так что упрёк  в неграмотности вы частично заслужили )

Comment: Никогда. А смысл? На крайний случай тогда был Quaid Analyzer, позволяюший патчить память по живому. Но даже в те древнеисторические времена код программ набирал в редакторе. Чего и всем желаю.

Comment: @klopp - и даже то, что автор вопроса запостил скриншот с запущенным дебагом (которого вы ни разу не видели и не разбираетесь), не остановило вас от поспешных выводов и необоснованной критики?

Comment: Видел-видел, лет 30 назад :) А почему я должен связывать этот листинг со скриншотом? Дебунгые программы не все же маньячно руками в нём же набирают. И в чём вы видите необоснованность?

Comment: @klopp - я не про листинг, а про скриншот, где в запущен процесс с заголовком окна `cmd.exe - debug`. и отвечая на вопрос с тегом `assembler`, у вас даже мысли не возникло о возможной связи между числами `11` и `17`?  )))

Comment: Это не сайт код-ревью, пример кода должен явно иллюстрировать проблему, которая может возникнуть у кого-то еще.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff дебагом пользуются три с половиной человека, так что пояснения не помешали бы. Это все-таки legacy system

Comment: "Элемент массива - 32-х разрядное 16-ричное знаковое число (12223278h)." - числа не бывают шестнадцатеричными. Числа - это числа.

Comment: ДА ИДИТЕ ВЫ УЖЕ НА ЭННОЕ КОЛИЧЕСТВО БУКВ. абы придраться! честное слово! ну зачем лезть со своими придирками??? что изменилось бы от того, если б я написал "число в 16-ричной системе счисления"?

Comment: Abyx, я выложил скриншотом результат выполнения программы.

Answer (score 3):

Разбираться в вашем нагромождении кода, пытаться понять его логику и вылавливать где именно ошибка очень непросто. Если у вас основная задача - перемножить два 32-разрядных числа на 16-разрядном процессоре, то и решать её нужно отдельно для начала. Например, по такому шаблону:

```
;-----------
main:
    mov ax, 1234
    mov dx, 5678
    push word 04321h
    push word 08765h

    call mul32

    ret
;-----------
mul32:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    ; первый множитель: ax:dx
    ; второй множитель: [bp+8]:[bp+6]
    ;
    ; тут колдуете
    ;
    pop bp
    ; результат возвращаете в ax:dx
    ; если 32 бит мало - можно передать ещё одним
    ; параметром адрес буфера для результата
    ret 4
;-----------
```

Так - наглядней ведь, да? И исключаются ошибки, которые могут быть внесены сторонним кодом.

Вот когда на выходе из mul32 будете получать результат, стабильно равный результату в калькуляторе, для разных входных значений, тогда и другими вопросам заняться можно будет.

Да и другим будет куда проще разбираться в коде и подсказывать что не так. А пока - вряд ли кто-то захочет ломать глаза и мозг о вашу простыню из инструкций.

Comment: вот скажите, вы когда-нибудь вообще имели дело с таким умножением? 
а то только до оформления доколупываетесь...

Comment: Да, имел, и не только с таким. Но код за вас писать не буду. А предлагаю вам подумать над тем, как и себе жизнь облегчить, и сделать так, чтобы другие люди не закрывали ваш код сразу же после беглого взгляда на него.

Comment: @Dmitrevicz нервишки шалят? :)

Comment: так... пойдем другим путем...

Comment: Моя основная задача - перемножить 3 именно отрицательных числа. С положительными я разобрался, понимаю как их умножить, получаю правильный ответ. Но не до конца понимаю, как нужно работать с отрицательными числами. 

Если число положительное, то все просто: умножаю столбиком как в начальной школе. перемножаю в определенной последовательности младшие, старшие части, складываю с add, adc.
Но если я применяю тот же принцип к отрицательным числам, то результат неверный.

Подскажите (если вы говорите, что сталкивались) хоть по какому принципу нужно работать с этими отрицательными числами?

Comment: @Dmitrevicz проще всего учитывать знаки отдельно

Answer (score 0):

Рассматривайте 32-битные числа как двузначные числа по основанию 2^16:

```
(x0 + x1 b)(y0 + y1 b) = x0 y0 + (x0 y1 + x1 y0) b (mod b^2)
```

Таким образом, задача сводится к 32-битному произведению 16-битных чисел и сложению. В первой подзадаче нижнее слово вы получите встроенным умножением, а верхнее - рассмотрев целую часть `(x0 + x1 b)(y0 + y1 b) / b^2` для `b = 2^8`. Вторая подзадача решается с помощью такой же техники, примененной к операции сложения.

Настоящий вопрос - почему в нашей системе образования до сих пор преподают ассемблер для 8086? :)